# Writing and reading a zoo object - errors

Tags: r, file-io, zoo

I have a zoo object, prices, which, when I type class(prices), it returns “zoo.” I then create a file using:

```
write.zoo(prices, file = “foo”, index.name = “time”)
```

The resulting files looks like this:

"time" "AAPL.Adjusted" “SHY.Adjusted"
2013-05-01 60.31 84.12
2013-05-02 61.16 84.11
2013-05-03 61.77 84.08

I then try and read this file with this statement:

```
myData <- read.zoo(“foo”)
```

and I get this error:

Error in read.zoo(“foo") :
    index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4

I’ve tried a number of parameter settings and nothing seems to work. Help much appreciated.
Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has a header line so try:

```
z <- read.zoo("foo", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

The `check.names` part gives nicer looking column names but you could leave it out if that were not important.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It was the header I had overlooked. Thanks!